# Work around for view expnand level and readers fields?

Tags: xpages

There is an issue with documents not showing if expand level is used, readers fields are used and Don't show empty categories is set for the view.

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/entdocview.wss?uid=swg1LO58079

This is a closed APAR do to a duplicate.  It references the duplicate but I am not finding it.  I must admit I have not done much searches on that site.  Can anyone find the oher?

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Besides not using a view panel? ;)